# Binding with parameters

Tags: c++, templates, boost, binding

I have problem with binding parameters to function. Invoker class call function and it doesn't know about parameters. So I can't use placeholders in binding like:

```
v.invoke(boost::bind(&B::fun, this, _1));
```

I want to make something like this:

```
v.invoke(boost::bind(&B::fun, this, fun_p));
```

I need it because I want to pass function `A::fun` to `B::BFun`. `B::BFun` shouldn't call directly `A::fun`, but by using `B::fun`.

```
class A
{
public:
A(){}
   void fun(){
       std::wcout << "FunA" << std::endl;
   }
};

class Invoker
{
public:
    Invoker(){}
   template <typename Handler>
   void invoke(Handler f)
   {
    f();
   }
};


class B
{
public:
B(){}

template <typename Handler>
void BFun(Handler fun_p)
{
    Invoker v;
    v.invoke(boost::bind(&B::fun, this, fun_p)); <------- how to pass param. Not      placeholder
}

template <typename Handler>
void fun(Handler func)
{
    func();
    std::wcout << "FunB" << std::endl;
}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
A a;
B b;
b.BFun(boost::bind(&A::fun, &a));
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

You have two problems here.

**Problem 1:**  when passing a `bind` as a parameter to `bind`, you get a function composition: the result of the inner bind is evaluated and passed to the outer bind as a parameter. See the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds). To solve this problem you should wrap your function parameter with `protect`:

```
template <typename Handler>
void BFun(Handler fun_p)
{
    BFunImpl(boost::protect(fun_p));
}

template<tyename Handler>
void BFunImpl(Handler fun_p)
{
    Invoker v;
    v.invoke(boost::bind(&B::fun, this, fun_p));
}
```

**Problem 2:** you take an address of a function template. The compiler doesn't know what function to instantiate and take the address of. You can either use `static_cast` in order to cast to the type you need, or use the explicit syntax:

```
v.invoke(boost::bind(&B::template fun<Handler>, this, fun_p));
```

Now it compiles fine.

Comment: Nice. Its hard to understood this on my example. But thanks. I figure it out on less complex.

Comment: I don't understand Problem 1. Where is function composition?

Comment: @userbb: `main` invokes `BFun` with `bind(&A::fun, &a)` as the parameter `fun_p`. So substituting it to `BFun` directly, you see that your expression inside `BFun` is equivalent to `bind(&B::fun, this, bind(&A::fun, &a))`. This is the `bind` nesting that is treated as a special case by the implementation.

Comment: @userbb: invoking `bind(&B::fun, this, bind(&A::fun, &a))()` is equivalent to `this->B::fun(a.A::fun())` which is obviously wrong since `a.A::fun()` is `void`.